# Why does changing a runtime parameter cause a rebuild in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

The title is fairly self explanatory. Whenever I do a build in Delphi 2010, if afterward all I change is the run parameter under Run -> Parameters, Delphi insists on rebuilding my application. In any other language/IDE I've ever used, that wouldn't happen. It wouldn't be a big problem if it weren't for the fact that a build takes about a minute each time.

Any ideas on how, if anything, I can do to keep it from doing this?

Thanks,
--David

Comment: Been that way in D2007 too, but not in D7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've noticed this too, and I agree that it's annoying.  Not sure exactly what the technical reasons are behind it. Probably something to do with the .dproj having changed.  You should file a bug report about this on QC.

Comment: +1; I think it is a bug too; @Davidguygc: please QC a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not certain if it is a change in the dproj. I've changed it in the window and then canceled and it would still cause a rebuild. I'll report it Monday. Thanks for the input. 

--David

Comment: The fact that runtime parameters are included in the .dproj file should itself be considered a ***nasty*** bug! That is just one of a number of settings that should **not** be version controlled sitting inside the same file as a number of settings that **should** be version controlled.